# Eclipse C++: Setting Compiler Options For Specific Files

Tags: c++, eclipse, cuda

I have a CUDA C++ project I am writing and compiling using Eclipse Nsight. My goal is to end up with an executable from the file that contains the main function, then to produce an individual shared library for each class in the project without needing to compile outside of the IDE. I can do this by creating a project for each class, then including all of them in the main project, but I would like a way to write all the files in a single Eclipse project and still end up with the desired artifacts. The project structure is as follows:

```
ClassA.h
ClassA.cu
ClassB.h
ClassB.cu
main.cpp
```

I am looking to compile the project and end up with the following artifacts:

```
ClassA.so
ClassB.so
main.exe
```

Ideally, I would like to know if there is a way to group specific files and set the compiler options for just that group of files. i.e.

```
nvcc ClassA.cu -shared -fPIC -o ClassA.so
nvcc ClassB.cu -shared -fPIC -o ClassB.so
g++  main.cpp -lClassA.so -lClassB.so -o main.exe
```

I know this is an unusual request, but this is part of a larger project architecture I am trying to bring from the land of emacs and compile shell scripts into the world of IDEs.

Comment: If you're willing to build/maintain your own makefile, you can start a nsight EE project from a makefile.  Really, the multiproject feature in both Eclipse and Visual Studio ("solution") is designed for this, so it's not clear why you wouldn't use the path that's designed for this type of structure.

Comment: The multi project route works, and that is what I am currently doing, but it is a bit clunky as I will need to have a project per class that uses my library. This could get out of hand quickly. I think the best idea is to go the custom makefile route... Oh well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option A: Write and maintain a custom make file.

Option B: Create 3 projects - exe and two shared libraries.

Comment: This is what I was afraid of. Neither option is really what I want, but I can work with this. Thank you!